# Azure function -- how to install package in python with corporate proxy

Tags: azure-functions

My company has corporate proxy. So, in normal python environment, if I need to install a package, I use this way:

```
   pip install --proxy=proxy-xxx.yyy.ddd.com:0000 pandas
```

However, when goes to Azure function, there is only one requriement.txt where I write the library you need.

e.g. I just write these in the requirement.txt:

```
Azure.functions
Pandas
```

But in this way, when I debug in VS Code, it will give me error such as timeout

So how can I deal with this?

B

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing **Pandas** with proxy in **VS code** but  it's not installed.

I Changed the path to **.venv** as below,

[image]

I run the below proxy command in my command prompt terminal,

```
pip install --proxy=proxy-xxx.yyy.ddd.com:0000 pandas
```

[image]

Then, I tried installing the [Azure-Function](https://pypi.org/project/azure-functions/) and [Panads](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) with pypi.org and got installed suceesfully as below,

[image]